# input type display none with less

Tags: css, less

I have this css piece of code (which is generated from a less file, but I don't know anything about less and this code is a piece of a global css file which include all generated code from all less file).

I'm looking for the less equivalent to this piece of css code to find which file I need to modify.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the less equivalent" - LESS is just a preprocessor; you could potentially write this a few different ways. Can you not search your stylesheets for `type="checkbox"` or something?

Comment: Well I tried but when you have more than a hundred occurences...with a syntax you don't really understand...obviously if in less there was a display:none I would have find it. But there isn't.

Comment: More than a hundred occurences of what specifically, `type="checkbox"`?... but you also say there are no occurences of `display: none`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really reverse engineer Less, but this style rule could show up in a number of ways. For example:

Using the & operator:

```
input{
    &[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

A selector var:

```
@my-selector: input[type="checkbox"];

@{my-selector}{
    display: none
}
```

A mix-in:

```
.dn() {
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  .dn();
}
```